# Export results of WCT run to use in CI tools

Tags: polymer, web-component-tester

I'm trying to integrate Web-components-tester into my CI build via CLI interface (WCT command) and at the moment I don't see a way to export test run results. Is there any flag or 3rd party plugin I can use to get this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no export available that I know of...
Since `wct` is `mocha`-based, you can try to integrate [mocha-allure-reporter](https://github.com/allure-framework/mocha-allure-reporter) and then use the corresponding framework!